# using ReflectionClass to read the class Properties

Tags: php

I am trying to read the properties of the following class through `ReflectionClass`
Now the Problem is the `tradingMarket` is an instance of `TradingMarket` class.
and if a variable is Object then i want to call the a function on that object that also returns the properties of said class.

```
class Certificate {
      private $isin;
      private $tradingMarket;
      private $currency;
      private $issuer;
      private $issuingPrice;
      private $currentPrice;
      private $priceHistory;
      private $documents;
      private $serializer;
}
```

Comment: judging by your previous two questions your Certificate has getters for these properties, so why would you need Reflection for it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion (not tested):

```
function getProperties($object) {
    $ref = new ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
    foreach ($reg->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED | ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE) as $prop) {
        if (is_object($prop->getValue($object)) getProperties($prop->getValue($object));
        else echo get_class($object)." => ".$prop->getName();
    }
}
```